# How can I reduce the size of a compiled Delphi code?

Tags: delphi, compilation, compiler-optimization

I just wrote a really short and simple code in **Delphi** with no even arrays neither data structures and when I compile it I get a **11 MB exe file**, it was compiled for 32 bits architecture under RAD Studio X3 IDE for 64 bits.

I think this isn't *optimal*, even a *jar* would weigh less!

Are there any settings I can do so I get a smaller compiled? Maybe any units I can dismiss in the code?

Comment: And [How to achieve smaller size of the executable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2150025/62576). Please at least do a scan through the `Related` list before posting your question to see if it's been asked and answered here before. You should also at least make an effort to search the site; searching for `[delphi] executable size` would have turned up both of the other links even if they weren't in the `Related` list.

Comment: Don't use VCL. Don't use FireMonkey. Don't use stock RTL. Use KOL/MCK for GUI and their modular RTL drop-in replacement. I did GUI-less DLLs as small as 2KB :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The How can I do that setting? I'm a total newbie for Delphi and gotta write a code for the weekend

Comment: @Arioch'The, KOL/MCK has been abandoned. It have *curio and relic* status nowadays.

Comment: You do realize that a JAR file is hardly going to run on some user's computer without a java runtime which is LARGER than 11 MB to download these days. :-)  Turn on the Use-Runtime-BPLs and you'll get your java style SMALL binary, that requires a huge amount of runtime ... And now you are becoming enlightened I hope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable debug information in your executable, which will strip out things like [debug symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol) from the executable. Check the [linker options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/C++_Linker) in RAD Studio on how to do this.

**Edit** (for the sake of validity/completion): You also have to switch to release instead of debug configuration - the linked question has an answer that's described in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598678/exe-size-is-too-big-in-delphi-xe2).

Options that will increase the size of your executable are:

- Full debug information: as mentioned, this will include debug symbols, which will make the size of your executable much bigger
- Link with Dynamic RTL: Controls if [Delphi Run Time Library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_the_RTL_%28Run-Time_Library%29) (RTL) is built into the executable, or as an external DLL. Embedding it in the executable with increase its size significantly
- Link with the Delphi Runtime Library

You can also pack your executable with an executable packer, like [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: One small thing to point out - if you do decide to use a packer like UPX, it helps to remember that this technique can often trick antivirus software into thinking that your executable is malware!  This is referred to as a 'false positive', and will give you a hard time when you release your software to the public.

Comment: This is a very good and wise advice, thanks!