# Make smaller Delphi executables

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

How can i make Delphi XE5 executables smaller? I already have them set to Release mode.
I tried to enable "Link with runtime packages" but then some people get errors that file are missing. Does someone know a way to make them smaller?

Comment: Are you sure with `VLC` tag? Or do you mean `VCL`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to achieve smaller size of the executable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2150025) and [EXE Size is too big in Delphi XE2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13598678) and [What Can I Do To Reduce My Executable's Size (Delphi)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3199476) and [How can I reduce the size of a compiled Delphi code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17119132)