# What are the primary differences between 'gc' and 'gccgo'?

Tags: go, gccgo

What are the primary differences between the two popular Go compilers, 'gc' and 'gccgo'?  Build performance? Run-time performance? Command line options?  Licensing?

I'm not looking for opinions on which is best, just a basic overview of their differences, so I can decide which is best for my needs.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can see more in "[Setting up and using gccgo](https://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo)":

> gccgo, a compiler for the Go language. The gccgo compiler is a new frontend for GCC.
>   Note that gccgo is not the gc compiler

As explained in "[Gccgo in GCC 4.7.1](http://blog.golang.org/gccgo-in-gcc-471)" (July 2012)

> The Go language has always been defined by a spec, not an implementation. The Go team has written two different compilers that implement that spec: gc and gccgo.
>
> - Gc is the original compiler, and the go tool uses it by default.
> - Gccgo is a different implementation with a different focus
>
> Compared to gc, gccgo is slower to compile code but supports more powerful optimizations, so a CPU-bound program built by gccgo will usually run faster.

Also:

> - The gc compiler supports only the most popular processors: x86 (32-bit and 64-bit) and ARM.
> - Gccgo, however, supports all the processors that GCC supports.
>     Not all those processors have been thoroughly tested for gccgo, but many have, including x86 (32-bit and 64-bit), SPARC, MIPS, PowerPC and even Alpha.
>     Gccgo has also been tested on operating systems that the gc compiler does not support, notably Solaris.
>
> if you install the go command from a standard Go release, it already supports gccgo via the `-compiler` option: `go build -compiler gccgo myprog`.

---

In short: **gccgo: more optimization, more processors**.

---

However, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811445/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-go-and-gccgo#comment40376438_25811505) by [OneOfOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145587/oneofone) ([source](https://golang.org/doc/go1.3#gccgo)), there is often a desynchronization between go supported by gccgo, and the latest go release:

> **gccgo only supports up to version go v1.2**, so if you need anything new in 1.3 / 1.4 (tip) gccgo cant be used. –
>
> **[GCC release 4.9](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.9/) will contain the Go 1.2 (not 1.3) version of gccgo**.
>   The release schedules for the GCC and Go projects do not coincide, which means that 1.3 will be available in the development branch but that the next GCC release, 4.10, will likely have the Go 1.4 version of gccgo.

---

[twotwotwo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2714852/twotwotwo) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811445/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-go-and-gccgo#comment40381603_25811505) the [slide of Brad Fitzpatrick's presentation](http://talks.golang.org/2014/gocon-tokyo.slide#54)

> gccgo generates very good code
>   ... but lacks escape analysis: kills performance with many small allocs + garbage
>   ... GC isn't precise. Bad for 32-bit.

twotwotwo adds:

> Another slide mentions that non-gccgo ARM code generation is wonky.
>   Assuming it's an interesting option for your project, probably compare binaries for your use case on your target architecture.

---

As [peterSO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221700/peterso) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811445/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-gc-and-gccgo/25811505?noredirect=1#comment54456058_25811505), [Go 1.5](https://golang.org/doc/go1.5) now (Q3/Q4 2015) means:

> The compiler and runtime are now written entirely in Go (with a little assembler).
>   **C is no longer involved in the implementation, and so the C compiler that was once necessary for building the distribution is gone**.

[The "Go in Go" slide](https://talks.golang.org/2015/gogo.slide#2) do mention:

> C is gone.
>   Side note: gccgo is still going strong.

---

[Berkant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4792552/berkant) asks [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811445/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-gc-and-gccgo/25811505#comment100933821_25811505) if `gccgo` is what `gc` was bootstrapped from.

[Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%C3%B6rg-w-mittag) answers:

> No, `gccgo` appeared after `gc`.
>
> `gc` was originally written in C. It is based on Ken Thompson's C compiler from the [Plan9 operating system](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs), the successor to Unix, designed by the same people. `gc` was iteratively refactored to have more and more of itself written in Go.
>
> `gccgo` was started by [Ian Lance Taylor](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor), a GCC hacker not affiliated with the Go project.
>
> Note that the first fully self-hosted Go compiler was actually a proprietary commercial closed-source implementation for Windows whose name seems to have vanished from my brain the same way it did from the Internet. They claimed to have a self-hosted compiler written in Go, targeting Windows at a time where `gccgo` did not yet exist and `gc` was extremely painful to set up on Windows. (You basically had to set up a full Cygwin environment, patch the source code and compile from source.)  The company seems to have folded, however, before they ever managed to market the product.

**Hector Chu** did release a Windows port of Go in Nov. 2009.
And the [`go-lang.cat-v.org/os-ports`](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/os-ports) page mentions **Joe/Joseph Poirier** initial work as well. In [this page](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/irc-logs/go-nuts/2010-06-14):

> Any chance that someone in the know could request that
>   one of the guys (**Alex Brainman** - Hector Chu - Joseph Poirier) involved in
>   producing the Windows port could make a wiki entry detailing their build
>   environment?

Add to that (in [Writing Web Apps in Go](https://talks.golang.org/2011/Writing_Web_Apps_in_Go.pdf)) **!光京 (Wei Guangjing)**.

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/go1.3#gccgo And more importantly gccgo only supports up to version go v1.2, so if you need anything new in 1.3 / 1.4 (tip) gccgo cant be used.

Comment: @OneOfOne good point, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: bradfitz's [slide on it](http://talks.golang.org/2014/gocon-tokyo.slide#54) mentions that it lacks escape analysis, where the compiler figures out some things can be allocated on the stack, and that its GC isn't precise. Another slide mentions that non-gccgo ARM code generation is wonky. Assuming it's an interesting option for your project, probably compare binaries for your use case on your target architecture.

Comment: @twotwotwo good find. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I read that gccgo implements goroutines by giving each goroutine a dedicated thread (as opposed to multiplexing many goroutines onto one thread). If this is still true then that can be a major difference to some people.

Comment: The root cause of all pros and cons is of course that gccgo is a GCC front-end: it parses GO into some GCC internal representation (at least GIMPLE I imagine), while `gc` is a completely dedicated compiler end to end (TODO check: was it written from scratch?)

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚胡海峰 at least, gc in Go 1.5 will be gone: https://talks.golang.org/2015/gogo.slide#2

Comment: @VonC: "gc in Go 1.5 will be gone" That's not true. [Go 1.5 Release Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.5). The slide (https://talks.golang.org/2015/gogo.slide#2) correctly says "C is gone", not "gc is gone".

Comment: @peterSO True, I have included your command in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: How has this changes over time? Now in 2019

Comment: @LeoGallucci The general idea in this answer stands with Go 1.11 ("gccgo: more optimization, more processors."). You can see a more recent illustration in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46970176/6309.

Comment: Can I say that gccgo is what gc was bootstrapped from, or? I know there was a compiler written in C to compile a Go compiler but was that gccgo? If all gc compiler executables were lost in a second, would they have to recompile it using gccgo? Could you enlighten me?

Comment: @Berkant Not sure: gc and gccgo have manifestly their own independent evolution: https://github.com/quasilyte/gccgo_vs_gc, https://meltware.com/2019/01/16/gccgo-benchmarks-2019.html

Comment: Also, `gc` is under BSD-style license while `gccgo` is under GPL.

Comment: anyone noticed that gccgo is not supported on macos?
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/3e7b85061947bdc7c7465743ba90734566860821/configure#L3521-L3527


Any solutions?

Comment: @ackratos That was noticed before indeed: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41765665/6309

Comment: @Berkant: No, gccgo appeared after gc. gc was originally written in C. It is based on Ken Thompson's C compiler from the [Plan9 operating system](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs), the successor to Unix, designed by the same people. gc was iteratively refactored to have more and more of itself written in Go. gccgo was started by Ian Lance Taylor, a GCC hacker not affiliated with the Go project. Note that the first fully self-hosted Go compiler was actually a proprietary commercial closed-source implementation for Windows whose name seems to have vanished from my brain the same

Comment: … way it did from the Internet. They claimed to have a self-hosted compiler written in Go, targeting Windows at a time where gccgo did not yet exist and gc was extremely painful to set up on Windows. (You basically had to set up a full Cygwin environment, patch the source code and compile from source.) The company seems to have folded, however, before they ever managed to market the product.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. I did not find that commercial port you mention, only the original Windows port (in 2009) done by Alex Brainman - Hector Chu - Joseph Poirier and  !光京 (Wei Guangjing).

Comment: @VonC: I a sure it was something with "e", and may have been a play on "ego". (Which, of course, someone else also had the idea, and it now seems to be a web framework.)