# Why are binaries built with gccgo smaller (among other differences?)

Tags: go, gccgo

I've been experimenting with gc and gccgo, and I've encountered some odd behaviour.

Using a [program](https://gist.github.com/evertheylen/df80a46fd7c96215af62) I once wrote to test some theorem, I got these results: (I removed unnecessary information for readablitity)

```
$ time go build -compiler gc -o checkprog_gc checkprog.go (x 3)
go build <...>    0.13s user 0.02s system 100% cpu 0.149 total
go build <...>    0.13s user 0.01s system 99%  cpu 0.148 total
go build <...>    0.14s user 0.03s system 100% cpu 0.162 total
 --> average:     0.13s user 0.02s system 100% cpu 0.153 total


$ time go build -compiler gccgo -o checkprog_gccgo checkprog.go (x 3)
go build <...>    0.10s user 0.03s system 96% cpu 0.135 total
go build <...>    0.12s user 0.01s system 96% cpu 0.131 total
go build <...>    0.10s user 0.01s system 92% cpu 0.123 total
 --> average:     0.11s user 0.02s system 95% cpu 0.130 total


$ strip -s -o checkprog_gc_stripped checkprog_gc
$ strip -s -o checkprog_gccgo_stripped checkprog_gccgo

$ ls -l
 1834504 checkprog_gc*
 1336992 checkprog_gc_stripped*
   35072 checkprog_gccgo*
   24192 checkprog_gccgo_stripped*

$ time ./checkprog_gc
./checkprog_gc  6.68s user 0.01s system 100% cpu 6.674 total
./checkprog_gc  6.75s user 0.01s system 100% cpu 6.741 total
./checkprog_gc  6.66s user 0.00s system 100% cpu 6.643 total
 --> average:   6.70s user 0.01s system 100% cpu 6.686 total

$ time ./checkprog_gccgo
./checkprog_gccgo  10.95s user 0.02s system 100% cpu 10.949 total
./checkprog_gccgo  10.98s user 0.01s system 100% cpu 10.964 total
./checkprog_gccgo  10.94s user 0.01s system 100% cpu 10.929 total
 --> average       10.96s user 0.01s system 100% cpu 10.947 total
```

I can see the following patterns:

1. Binaries built with `gccgo` are radically smaller in size (and stripping doesn't help to change this difference)
2. Binaries built with `gc` are faster to execute
3. It takes a bit more time to build with `gccgo` than with `gc`

I also tested some other go programs (while not that extensively) and all of them exhibit the same behavior.

This seems to contradict what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25811505/2678118) states:

> In short: **gccgo: more optimization, more processors.**

I'd think that more optimization means faster binaries, while needing more time to compile...

**What's the reason these three patterns?**

Comment: Most probably that's because they're linked to `libgo`. `ldd` or `readelf` would tell you (if you're on a Linux system).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a bunch of differences--[bradfitz talked about some of them in a May 2014 talk](http://talks.golang.org/2014/gocon-tokyo.slide):

- `gccgo` can produce a binary that dynamically links in `libgo`, which makes the output smaller but means the relevant library to be installed on the target machine. Go binaries without `cgo` don't have that requirement.
- `gccgo` does more low-level optimizations 'cause it can use `gcc`'s code generator and optimizer. Writing some data-compression code, gccgo ran it noticeably faster than `gc`. Those same optimizations make the compiler slower: it's doing more work.
- `gccgo` supports the target processors that `gcc` does, so it's the only way to get on some architectures like SPARC, ARMv8 (64-bit) or POWER.  (Canonical uses it to compile their Juju service orchestration tool for arm64 and ppc64.)
- `gccgo` and `gc` both support ARMv7 (32-bit), but according to bradfitz's talk `gc` does not generate the most efficient ARM code.
- There are certain optimizations only `gc` has.

  - A big one is [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis), in which the compiler determines that some variables will never "escape" the function where they're allocated and therefore can be stack-allocated. (So, surprisingly, `new(T)` may not heap-allocate if its return value doesn't escape.) This reduces how often garbage collection needs to run.
  - Another is that `.s` assembler files in the standard library are only linked in by `gc`, so some stuff like Intel hardware CRC32C isn't used by `gccgo` by default (you'd have to provide an implementation specifically for gccgo).
- `gc` implements new language features first and has generally been a minor Go version or two ahead of the latest `gccgo` .

Comment: (Made this CW 'cause there is potentially a lot to say about gc/gccgo differences, I'm not really an expert, and I'd love folks who know more to edit it in.)

Answer (score 8):

The size is different because gc makes static binaries and gccgo links to libgo. This means that the code for the entire runtime (scheduler, garbage collector, maps, channels) is not in the final binary created by gccgo.

The speed of compile will of course favor gc. GC was built with speed of compilation in mind. It also generally makes less optimized code and has less work it needs to perform.

Now on to why gc is still faster. The truth is that neither of them are always faster than the other. For example, try to md5 a file and GCCGO will be an order of magnitude faster. Try to implement something with a lot of channels and gc will surely win. You can't always tell ahead of time which will succeed. GC tends to have more efficient concurrency and gccgo tends to be better at math. However, this is something you need to test on a case by case basis. Preferably using go test's benchmarking system and not time.