# Delphi programs are detected as false-positive by ClamAV

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, antivirus, false-positive

My Delphi XE2 programs are **always** detected as containing a virus on [Jotti](http://virusscan.jotti.org/en) by ClamAV, while other virus scanners do not detect anything:

[image]

AFAIK, **ClamAV** is often used with mail servers. So do I have to fear that end-users will get a virus warning when sending my program by e-mail (even when zipped)?

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Submit your program to the av company

Comment: Maybe they're still having [`problems with PUA detection`](http://forums.clamwin.com/viewtopic.php?p=15587#15587).

Comment: Please try to send your own Delphi programs to Jotti. Are they also detected as false-positive?

Comment: Er no. You can send your own program to the av vendor. Why would we do that?

Comment: To get information also for other people whether Delphi programs GENERALLY are detected as false-positive by ClamAV. PS: Maybe this is a misunderstanding: I meant to send them to Jotti for TESTING! Jotti is a TESTING service!

Comment: Many malware makers like Delphi.  Idiot AV vendors sometimes use part of the runtime library as a signature.

Comment: -1 this question does not belong on SO.

Comment: Do you use a packer like UPX? This increase the number of false positive by an big ratio, [without any real benefit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353634). It is preferred to zip the exe before running it.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez No, I don't use the UPX packer for this exact reason. The programs are just normally compiled by Delphi XE2. (Default Release build)

Comment: @user1580348, If you google the title of your question : `Delphi programs are detected as false-positive` you have a 100% chance of finding an answer to your question in the top 5 search result links. I hope you understand now why this question shouldn't be asked in the first place.

Comment: @user1580348, It's not illogical when you actually read the guidelines. That would be the logical thing to do, just as it is logical to first research your problem before posting another useless question. Your question is a duplicate at best and I'm sorry if my opinion upsets you, I would suggest that you next time properly research on your problem prior to posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Possibly Unwanted Applications](https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/faq-pua.md) according to them and you can't report PUAs on their [false positive upload form](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/sendvirus/submit-fp/).

Their [contacts page](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/contacts/) shows two possible avenues you can follow: subscribe and post to their ClamAV mailing-list, or file a bug report in Bugzilla.

A strong argument when reporting is that no one else flags your programs.

Did you also try [Virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/)?

Comment: Strange: When scanned on VirusTotal, ClamAV does not report a false-positive with the **SAME** program! (While on Jotti it is reported, see the above screenshot).

Comment: It may be that Virustotal has PUA detection off, while Jotti has it on. See the notes in TLamas's link.