# Windows Defender detects my own Inno Setup as Virus

Tags: installation, fonts, inno-setup, virus

I have created a Setup that does install .otf files.
The Problem I have now is that it gets detected as Virus.
Can someone help me to avoid this?

Here a Code-example of one .otf-file:

```
Source: "{#Fontpath}MMaFermat-Bold.otf"; DestDir: "{autofonts}"; FontInstall: "MMa Fermat"; Flags: 
fontisnttruetype  onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```

Here some Images from the VM:

[image]
[image]

Best Regards,

Christian

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65840311/build-exe-file-with-false-positive-delphi

Comment: Well all I added to the previous version were Fonts so fonts can give false positives? Oh man :(

Comment: False positive are truly annoying. They make me hate people who write malware and viruses.

Comment: Is your installer signed by EV code signing certificate? See [Microsoft SmartScreen - suspended using Inno Setup installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29067877/850848).

Comment: @Martin Prikryl no it is not^^ It was just an installer for myself. The real installer just unpacked the files without showing it in the control panel.

Comment: These days, you cannot expect to be able to run an unsigned exe from internet or installer from any source without it being blocked by an antivirus.